# Is classical lambda calculus grammar an `LL(k)` one?

Tags: lambda-calculus, parsing

I am playing with a lambda calculus and faced a question I find hard to reason about.

On the screenshot you may find *the* lambda calculus grammar. Is it an instance of the `LL(k)` grammar such that a recursive descent parser could handle it? How do you proof such a statement? What would be the best hint here?

[image: Lambda calculus.]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some trivial factorization, I think it should be easy to prove it's LL(1) by constructing the LL(1) table for it. The grammar would be:

```
M ::= x | ( N )
N ::= λx.M | M M
```

Without the factorization, if you consider the simpler, obvious grammar:

```
M ::= x | (λx.Μ) | (Μ Μ)
```

it's not LL(1), as the second and third alternative share a common prefix `(`, but it's LL(2). In any case, you can definitely construct a recursive descent parser for it.

---

**Edit:** Adding a (non-standard, I must say) rule for redundant parentheses around terms complicates things. The following grammar is not LL(k) for any value of k:

```
M ::= x | (λx.Μ) | (Μ Μ) | (M)
```

The reason is that, in order to decide between the third and the fourth alternative, a predictive parser would have to read the common prefix `(M`, which can be arbitrarily long.

However, after factorization, the following equivalent grammar is again LL(1):

```
M ::= x | (N)
N ::= λx.Μ | Μ L
L ::= Μ | ε
```

Comment: But this way you won't be able to `(x)` for example or `((\x . x))`, right?

Comment: Seems that you are missing the `M := (M)` case, which indeed was not mentioned at the screenshot I've posted, yet assumed.

Comment: @Zazaeil, I edited the answer. Let me comment, however, that redundant parentheses are not part of *the* lambda calculus grammar.

Comment: thanks, I didn't know that.